# How to convert a JSON tree to a dynamic HTML table

Tags: javascript, json, node-red

(First allow me to say that I'm just beginning to learn Node-RED concepts; I went through some beginners' guides at nodered.org, and now am trying to extend what I learned so far).
I'm trying to build a flow that starts with a simple JSON tree like

```
[{"position":"1", "title":"element #1"},
{"position":"2", "title":"element #2"},
{"position":"3", "title":"element #3"}]
```

To build that treee I use a template node, property is set to `msg.payload`.
The number of array elements (in theory) is dynamic. To make sure that this tree is true JSON I added a JSON node converting from String to JSON object.

Next I wish to parse that object into a dynamic html table. For this I used a JS function node that's looping through the object and embedding its elements into the according html elements like this:

```
var return="";
for(var i=0;i<=msg.payload.length-1;i++){
    var row=msg.payload[i];
    if(row){
        return+="<tr>";
        return+="<td>"+row.position+"</td>";
        return+="<td>"+row.title+"</td>";
        return+="</tr>";
    }else{
        return+="no object at index "+i.toString();
    }
}
msg.payload=return;
return msg;
```

The output of the function then should be passed into a 2nd template like this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>#</td>
                <td>Title</td>
            </tr>
            {{ payload }}
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would have expected that the function's result is inserted into the static table of my template, and that happens indeed but not the way I hoped: somehow the html elements that got created by my function are not recognized as what they shoud be; instead I see that they are rendered as

```
&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;1&lt;&#x2F;td&gt;&lt;
```

instead of

```
<tr><td>1</td>
```

etc.

Result is that the browser does not recognize those elements and prints them together with their contents outside my static table

Questions:

- what do I need to do so that my 2nd template recognizes my computed string as a set of html elements?
- or is this probably a concept not suitable for my purpose?

Comment: minor point... `i<=msg.payload.length-1` is better as `i<msg.payload.length`

Comment: if you do a `console.log(row)` do you see the data you expect?

Comment: yes, I do; forgot to mention this in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using handelbars for your templating engine. In that case use:

```
{{{ payload }}}
```

Instead of

```
{{ payload }}
```

However a more elegant approach would be this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>#</td>
                <td>Title</td>
            </tr>
            {{#each payload}}
              <tr><td>{{this.position}}</td><td>{{this.title}}</td></tr>
            {{/each}}
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

then just

```
return msg.payload
```

Comment: perfect, that ({{{ payload }}}) did the trick. there was no mentioning of this in the beginners' guide. And I agree that the '{{#each}} variant in fact is what I had wished to use, if only I had know it exists :D. Really have to a bit more reading - thanks

Comment: just tried the other option; receive a debug message 'Unclosed section "each payload"'; changed the closing part to '{{/each payload}}' and that removes the error, but it leaves the table empty. still experimenting...

Comment: added my own answer cause I finally got your "elegant" code version to work, but with some small differences; would have been too long for a comment...

Answer (score 1):

again thanks to @als9xd for pointing me into the right direction; his 2nd idea indeed sounds much more elegant but first I couldn't get it to work. After some trial-and-error and looking up documentation for the template node I finally came up with this: removed the function node from my original question and then altered the 2nd template to this code:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>#</td>
                <td>Title</td>
            </tr>
            {{#payload}}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{position}}</td>
                    <td>{{title}}</td>
                </tr>
            {{/payload}}
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Difference to @als9xd's example is that I replaced `{{#each payload}}` with a simple `{{#payload}}`, plus omitted `this` when referencing the object keys.

Could this be due to different Node-RED versions?

Anyways this is starting to be much fun!